# How to embed a google-spreadsheet chart in a wordpress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-sheets

I would like to embed a chart in a wordpress post.
I am using the script generated by using the publish function in google sheets.

If I add the generated script to a generic html page, I can see the chart.

If I add the generated script to a wordpress post, I get the following error:
"All series on a given axis must be of the same data type×"

Do I need to modify the script or something else in the wordpress page to correctly visualize the chart?

Thanks

here is the code generated by Google-sheets:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/static/modules/gviz/1.0/chart.js"> {"dataSourceUrl":"//docs.google.com/spreadsheet/tq?key=0AgtmZPWzQ7lldEt2S2VLajBRQVNFLV9pRFY2bTRQLVE&transpose=0&headers=1&range=A2%3AB1010&gid=0&pub=1","options":{"titleTextStyle":{"bold":true,"color":"#000","fontSize":16},"curveType":"","animation":{"duration":500},"width":1270,"lineWidth":2,"hAxis":{"useFormatFromData":true,"title":"Data","minValue":null,"viewWindowMode":null,"viewWindow":null,"maxValue":null},"vAxes":[{"useFormatFromData":true,"title":"\u00b5g/m\u00b3","minValue":null,"logScale":false,"viewWindow":{"max":null,"min":null},"maxValue":null},{"useFormatFromData":true,"minValue":null,"logScale":false,"viewWindow":{"max":null,"min":null},"maxValue":null}],"booleanRole":"certainty","title":"Via Ariosto, SO2","height":469,"interpolateNulls":false,"legend":"right","focusTarget":"series","useFirstColumnAsDomain":false,"tooltip":{"trigger":"none"}},"state":{},"view":{},"isDefaultVisualization":false,"chartType":"LineChart","chartName":"Chart 1"} </script>
```

Comment: Wordpress has a habit of mangling raw HTML pasted into it. Your best bet would be to use a plugin like [Raw HTML Snippets](http://wordpress.org/plugins/raw-html-snippets/) to ensure that it leaves your code alone.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed it transformed & into &#038

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a WordPress plugin explicitly designed for integrating with the Google Charts API. The [Inline Google Spreadsheet Viewer plugin for WordPresss](https://wordpress.org/plugins/inline-google-spreadsheet-viewer/) uses a Google Spreadsheet as a datasource and lets you easily display that data in any of a number of Google Charts and graph visualizations.